# cosmos DB: select all items in a table using table name in query

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query in cosmosDB via node.js that will let me name the table in the query so I can select all items in that table.
the following setup works,

```
cosmosClient.database('samples')
  .container('container_id')
  .items.query(querySpec).toArray()
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

but I have to use the name of the table/collection as a parameter if the `container` method but what I want to achieve is a way to use a query like this: `SELECT * FROM colleciton_id...`
I see that cosmosDB has a `containers` prop that it says allows you to query against all containers/collections, but when I try it:

```
  cosmosClient.database('samples').containers.query(querySpec).toArray()
    .then(results => console.log(results))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I get an array of collection names instead of all the items in the specified collection.

is there a way to write a query against a collection without having to use `container(id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By container, the sdk means collection. The SQL query is executed at the collection level so if you write something like this `select * from xxx` then xxx doesn't have to be the name of the collection. CosmosDB will know which one you are targeting already and xxx will be something like an alias. The collection name is already defined at the `container()` method.

The `cosmosClient.database('samples').containers` method will return an enumarable of all the collections in the database.

What you need to do if you want a cross collection query is iterate over these collections and do this for each one of the collections.

```
cosmosClient.database('samples')
  .container(containerId)
  .items.query(querySpec).toArray()
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

where `containerId` is the current collectionid in your iteration.

I would however warn you that if a cross collection query is something you need then there might be something wrong with your database design.

Comment: crap! yeah, I had a gut-wrenching feeling that was the case. I need the ability to do things across collections as well (real joins) and I see that isn't possible as well just across documents

Comment: I guess I'll have to use an actual SQL DB for this